# Would a Class 10 MicroSDHC card ever be worth it on a Smartphone (Samsung Galaxy S 2)?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, external-sd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a Class 10 MicroSD overkill or is a Class 6 adequate?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5495/is-a-class-10-microsd-overkill-or-is-a-class-6-adequate)

first of all I am aware that there are similar questions, I've read them but they don't totally apply here.
I own a powerful Samsung Galaxy S 2 and I am getting a 32gb MicroSDHC card, however, I'd like to know if class 10 cars are totally useless compared to class 6, or do they ever get useful?

My phone is able to take 8megapixel photos and 1080p videos, is a class 6 way enough or a class 10 would be more appropriate?

I am asking this because that market evolves constantly and the other questions I saw were asking about class 2, 4, etc. As of now, Class 10 cars aren't really expensive so I wouldn't mind paying for it, however if I can't profit from its enhanced performance at all (compared to a sufficient **?** Class 6), I will save these extra bucks.

Comment: I'm assuming a class 6 came with your device, so that should be enough for videos. L3 video at 1080p is just over 5.5 MB/s so 6 MB/s is sufficient, and I've read that the S2 takes video at [up to 3 MB/s with a hack](http://samsunggalaxys2blog.com/samsung-galaxy-s2-tips/samsung-galaxy-s2-hacked-1080p-24-mbits-recording-hack/) so even a class 4 would work.

Comment: "Is it worth it?" is a question only you can answer; everyone else can only offer opinions. This is not the kind of question we prefer here. Please review the [FAQ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for such high class card. This card is used mainly for photography where speed and amount of data to be stored does count. Classic sample, sport photography where you are not taking just single shot, but whole burst of 10-20 shots and later on analyse which is best

Comment: That is the kind of information I wanted to know. According to Matthew Read, a class 6 would be perfect, thanks!